# Uploading image to folder and unlinking

Tags: php, html

I am uploading image to a folder. I can upload the image to the folder, but when I want to delete the image from the folder it doesn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
To delete the image from the folder I use the unlink method.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$images = "";

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

    foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'][$key]);
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type= $_FILES['file']['type'][$key];  

        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$key] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$key] < 2000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            //echo "<img src=upload/" . $file_name . ">";
            $images = $images . "<img src=upload/" . $file_name . "><br><a href='upload_file.php?deleteid=$file_name'>delete</a>";
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "upload/".$file_name);
            echo "Uploaded!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid file type!"; 
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {

    $image_to_delete = $_GET['deleteid'];

    //unlink the image from server
        // Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
    $pictodelete = ("upload/$image_to_delete");

    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
        unlink($pictodelete);
    }
    header("location: upload_file.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php echo $images; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. The image is still in the folder after deleting.

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($image_to_delete); ? I wouldn't use deleteid as a filename... and if you do that... what is the filename?

Comment: This code is **HIDEOUSLY** insecure and will allow a malicious user to delete **ANY** file on your server that they know the path. STOP working on this code until you've learned how to SAFELY process uploads and how to SAFELY allow a delete operation.

Comment: What should I read to on how to SAFELY process uploads? Where can I find information.

Comment: @EM10 Problem can occur from any of your `if` expressions for deleting. You have to check each of them and see whether they're performing their statements or not. For safety issues, I'd rather to say you that you have to make users restrict on these kinds of actions, besides I may suggest that it is better if you store your file names in a database table with a respective key and then receive the file id from browser instead of names and check it with your table for validation.